# Angular 2: binding model in window.functionName doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular

My current task is to attach external JS widget that from another service to Angular 2 project. This widget requires in params function declared in global scope as callback where it will return data.
My best idea to do it in angular 2 style is to describe function in class(code below).

```js
initWidget(){
  window.widgetCallback = function(result){
    this.deliveryPoint = result;
  };
  boxberry.open('widgetCallback', 'some', 'params');
}
```

This function works properly and **deliveryPoint** receives needed data but when i calling **{{deliveryPoint}}** in template, it has no any binding - variable not updating.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide more context. Where did you put this code? Where should `this.deliveryPoint` refer to?

Comment: It refers to method in class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell from your question what the problem is but I assume using `()=>` instead of `function ()` fixes your problem:

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

initWidget(){
  window.widgetCallback = (result) => {
    this.deliveryPoint = result;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  };
  boxberry.open('widgetCallback', 'some', 'params');
}
```

Comment: @yurzui why did you delete your answer. Seems right to me and you were faster. I just saw it after I posted mine (same with the update).

Comment: That's ok. I mixed `markForCheck` with `detectChanges`